# Upgrading to Dot Net Core Sql Problems

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, upgrade

So, I am trying to update my data project to use dot net core. I am slowly getting through all the errors. I am having trouble with this one though. I need to make an SqlQuery that returns a list, but as far as I am aware dot net core doesn't support that yet.

Here is the code

```
List<DateTime> result = this.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>(@"SELECT c.DateId FROM Schedule.Calendar c
WHERE c.DateId > @startDate AND c.DateId < @endDate AND c.IsWorkDay = 0",
     new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate), new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDate)).ToList();
```

I have a few more that are kinda like this, but I can't figure those out either. I am getting an error on the SqlQuery

It says thatDatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for SqlQuery. How would I go about updating this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code:

```
List<MyDateTime> result = this.Set<MyDateTime>().FromSql(@"SELECT Schedule.Workday(@startDate, @days)",
                new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDate), new SqlParameter("@days", days)).ToList();

            List<DateTime> finalResult = new List<DateTime>();

            foreach(MyDateTime myDate in result)
            {
                finalResult.Add(myDate.DateTime);
            }
```

This way I don't have to have a using or a certain context. I just created class with DateTime property to use as MyDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're trying to use Raw SQL but my preference would be to approach this scenario using Linq as:

```
List<DateTime> GetDateTimeResult(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int isWorkDay)
{
   using (var db = new YourScheduleDatabaseContext())
   {
     List<DateTime> result = db.Calendar
                               .Where(c => c.DateId > startDate)
                               .Where(c => c.DateId < endDate)
                               .Where(c => c.IsWorkDay.Equals(isWorkDay))
                               .Select(c => new DateTime(c.DateId)).ToList();
     return result;
   }
 }
```

I might have misunderstood your context name and table names but hope you get the idea and happy to help further.